# understanding how to Import variables from a method

Tags: python, variables

Lets say i have something like this:
This is file tree.py:

```
class leaf():
def green():
    x = 100
```

This is file view.py:

```
from tree import leaf.green 
g = green()
print g.x
```

How do i get the variable form subclass `green` 
I know for class its just:

This is file tree.py:

```
class leaf():

    x = 100
```

This is file view.py:

```
from tree import leaf 
class view():
 g = leaf()
 print g.x
```

I understand how to do it if both classes are in the same file. But i dont understand in two seprate files.
Thanks,
 John

Comment: I don't think you understand how to use classes in Python.

Comment: Terminology mixup: A subclass of a `class` C is a `class` that inherits from C. A `def` inside a `class` is a method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the root of your problem is that you need to learn more about how classes in Python work. Fortunately, the tutorial in the Python docs [has a section on classes](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/classes.html).

If that doesn't help, going through something like [Learn Python the Hard Way](http://learnpythonthehardway.org/static/LearnPythonTheHardWay.pdf) and doing the exercises can be immensely helpful.

Comment: i have been through that doc. I am still rather confused.

Comment: @John I've added another link that you might find helpful. Do you have any prior experience with object-oriented programming>

Comment: Yeah with Java. Its much easier with Java it seems. All right then i'll check out that PDF. Thanks

Comment: @John it's not easier I'd say, just a bit different. In Python, all instance methods (non-static in Java terms) must take `self` as their first argument (which is the instance), and instance variables are referred to from within the class as `self.var`

Comment: Yeah i understand all the `self.x` I am just confused about using something for a different file. http://pastebin.com/mrFyYAAa This is an example of my work

Comment: @John you can use `from other_module import SomeClass`. You cannot import methods, for that you should just write a function outside a class.

Comment: Alright from you and delnan's answers it seems i am doing something that you shouldn't do. I think i understand how i should do this thanks!

Comment: Yep just tested it out. I understand now. Thanks for that PDF btw, probably can learn something better from it.

Answer (score 1):

`x` is local to the method, i.e. it shouldn't (and can't, at least not easily) be accessed from the outside. Worse - it only exists while the method runs (and is removed after it returns).

Note that you *can* assign an attribute to a method (to any function, really):

```
class Leaf(object):
    def green(self):
        ...
    green.x = 100

print Leaf.green.x
```

But that's propably not what you want (for starters, you can't access it as a local variable inside the method - *because it isn't one*) and in fact very rarely useful (unless you have a really good reason not to, just use a class).

Comment: Your Correct. Thanks knowing you cant access the variable changed everything. I figure out how i wanted to do this