# Return values from one script to another script

Tags: python

I have the following script that will run each script (sequentially) in a directory:

```
import os

directory = []

for dirpath, dirnames, filenames in os.walk("path\to\scripts"):
    for filename in [f for f in filenames if f.endswith(".py")]:
        directory.append(os.path.join(dirpath, filename))
for entry in directory:
    execfile(entry)
    print x
```

my scripts look like this:

```
def script1():
    x = "script 1 ran"
    return x

script1()
```

When `print x` is called, it says x is not defined.  I'm just curious if there is a way to return values so that the parent script can access the data.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4807680/understanding-how-to-import-variables-from-a-method check this out.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> I'm just curious if there is a way to return values so that the parent script can access the data.

This is why you define functions and return values.

Script 1 should include a function.

```
def main():
    all the various bits of script 1 except the import 
    return x

if __name__ == "__main__":
    x= main()
    print( x )
```

Works the same as yours, but now can be used elsewhere

Script 2 does this.

```
import script1
print script1.main()
```

That's the way one script uses another.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the locals argument of execfile(). Write the scripts like this:

```
def run_script():
    ret_value = 2
    return ret_value

script_ret = run_script()
```

And in your main script:

```
script_locals = dict()
execfile("path/to/script", dict(), script_locals)
print(script_locals["script_ret"])
```

Answer (score 1):

`x` is local to the `script1` function, so it's not visible in the outer scope. If you put the code inside `script1` at the top level of the file, it should work.